# What the following macro mean?

Tags: c, macros

The below code defines a macro but I don't know how it works. I need an explanation.

```
    typedef struct 
    {
    char *cmdname;       /* String containing the name of the command    */
    void (*func)(int);   /* Pointer to the action function */
    char *help;          /* Help string for the command */
    } parse_table;

    #define ADD_CMD(name,f,helptxt) \
    const parse_table f##E __attribute__ ((section(".parsetable." name)))    = { \
    .cmdname = name,  \
    .func    = f, \
    .help    = helptxt };
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? Looks like VS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/503x3e3s.aspx

Comment: my prof gave me these code. I am not understanding these "__attribute__ ((section(".parsetable." name)))"  section

Comment: I'd rather see `const char*` as the structure elements.

Comment: You should ask your prof after reading the documentation if you still don't understand it.

Comment: `__attribute__ ((section ...` is a gcc-specific extension - see the gcc manual for further details. The rest is just straightforward C99 struct initialisation.

Answer (score 1):

If you use that macro as

```
ADD_CMD("abc1", func_abc1, "abc1 help text")
ADD_CMD("abc2", func_abc2, "abc2 help text")
ADD_CMD("abc3", func_abc3, "abc3 help text")
```

it will be expanded by preprocessor to

```
const parse_table func_abc1E __attribute__ ((section(".parsetable." "abc1"))) =
{ .cmdname = "abc1", .func = func_abc1, .help = "abc1 help text" };
const parse_table func_abc2E __attribute__ ((section(".parsetable." "abc2"))) =
{ .cmdname = "abc2", .func = func_abc2, .help = "abc2 help text" };
const parse_table func_abc3E __attribute__ ((section(".parsetable." "abc3"))) =
{ .cmdname = "abc3", .func = func_abc3, .help = "abc3 help text" };
```

So it allows you to define and assign many similar structures by writing `ADD_CMD` lines.

The macro `ADD_CMD()` just substitutes its arguments and does [Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html) for `f`:

> The ‘##’ preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro
>   is expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are
>   combined into a single token, which then replaces the ‘##’ and the two
>   original tokens in the macro expansion.